# Writing Fixed width text files from excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

This is the output of a program.

[image: Current Output of my program]

I have specified what shall be width of each cell in the program and my program shows correct output.

What I want to do is cell content shall be written from right to left. E.g highlighted figure 9983.54 has width of 21. Text file has used first 7 columns. But I want it to use last 7 columns of text file.

Please see expected output image.

[image: Expected output]

I am not getting any clue how to do this. I am not a very professional programmer but I love coding. This text file is used as input to some other program and i am trying to automate writing text file from excel VBA.

Can anyone suggest a way to get this output format?

Here is the code which gave me first output

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateFixedWidthFile(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet, s() As Integer)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim strLine As String, strCell As String

    'get a freefile
    Dim fNum As Long
    fNum = FreeFile

    'open the textfile
    Open strFile For Output As fNum
    'loop from first to last row
    'use 2 rather than 1 to ignore header row
    For i = 1 To ws.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
        'new line
        strLine = ""
        'loop through each field
        For j = 0 To UBound(s)
            'make sure we only take chars up to length of field (may want to output some sort of error if it is longer than field)
            strCell = Left$(ws.Cells(i, j + 1).Value, s(j))
            'add on string of spaces with length equal to the difference in length between field length and value length
            strLine = strLine & strCell & String$(s(j) - Len(strCell), Chr$(32))
        Next j
        'write the line to the file
        Print #fNum, strLine
    Next i
    'close the file
    Close #fNum

End Sub
```

'for example the code could be called using:

```
Sub CreateFile()
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Text Files,*.txt")
    If LCase$(sPath) = "false" Then Exit Sub
    'specify the widths of our fields
    'the number of columns is the number specified in the line below +1
    Dim s(6) As Integer
    'starting at 0 specify the width of each column
    s(0) = 21
    s(1) = 9
    s(2) = 15
    s(3) = 11
    s(4) = 12
    s(5) = 10
    s(6) = 186
    'for example to use 3 columns with field of length 5, 10 and 15 you would use:
    'dim s(2) as Integer
    's(0)=5
    's(1)=10
    's(2)=15
    'write to file the data from the activesheet
    CreateFixedWidthFile sPath, ActiveSheet, s
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code that generated the first screenshot

Comment: yes. updated. Please see

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
x = 9983.54
a = Space(21-Len(CStr(x))) & CStr(x)
```

Then a will be 14 spaces followed by x:

```
a = "              9983.54"
```

Here 21 is the desired column width --- change as necessary. `CStr` may be unnecessary for non-numeric x.

If you're going to right-justify a lot of different data to different width fields you could write a general purpose function:

```
Function LeftJust(val As String, width As Integer) As String
    LeftJust = Space(width - Len(val)) & val
End Function
```

The you call it with `LeftJust(CStr(9983.54), 21)`.

Also note that VBA's `Print #` statement has a `Spc(n)` parameter that you can use to produce fixed-width output, e.g., `Print #fNum, Spc(n); a`; before this statement you calculate n: `n = 21-Len(CStr(a))`.

Hope that helps